# Powershell script to create a windows catalog file

Tags: xml, powershell, audit, bin

I have few commands in Powershell to execute to create a catalog which consists of all whitelisted softwares.

For that I need to add some content to the XML file, save it and convert it to binary(.bin) file.
Next step will be copy the contents from that converted bin file to policy.p7b file.

Now restart the machine(shutdown -r -t 1)

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass
C:\>notepad C:\ProgramData\<some path>\CurrentComplete.xml
```

Now add the content inside that .xml file.

```
<Rule>
<Option>Enabled:Audit Mode</Option>
</Rule>
```

Save and exit

Now convert that .xml file to binary using below:

```
ConvertFrom-CIPolicy -XmlFilePath "C:\ProgramData\<some path>\CurrentComplete.xml" -BinaryFilePath C:\CurrentPolicyInAudit.bin
```

Now move this .bin to a policy file:

```
move C:\CurrentPolicyInAudit.bin C:\Windows\System32\CodeIntegrity\SiPolicy.p7b
```

Once it is done you can restart the machine.

So how to make it as automated, I mean now I need to put it a file and execute in Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying XML using Xml Linq would look like this

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
$filename = 'C:\ProgramData\<some path>\CurrentComplete.xml'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
$option = $doc.Descendants("Option")[0]

$option.SetValue('Enabled:Audit Mode')

$doc.Save($filename)
```

Comment: I am getting this error:  
PS C:\Users\Santosh\Downloads> $filename = '.\CICurrentComplete.xml'
PS C:\Users\Santosh\Downloads> $doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\CICurrentComplete.xml'."
At line:1 char:1
+ $doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

Comment: You need to modify the filename.